# How can you list the matches of Vim's search?

Tags: search, vim

I would like to list the matches, when I hit:

```
/example
```

so that I see where all matches are at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    " put in your ~/.vimrc file
    " START search related configs and helps
    "
    " ignore case when searching
    set ignorecase

    " search as characters are entered, as you type in more characters, the search is refined
    set incsearch

    " highlight matches, in normal mode try typing * or even g* when cursor on string
    set hlsearch

    " yank those cheat commands, in normal mode type q: than p to paste in the opened cmdline
    " how-to search for a string recursively
    " :grep! "\<doLogErrorMsg\>" . -r
    "
    " how-to search recursively , omit log and git files
    " :vimgrep /srch/ `find . -type f \| grep -v .git \| grep -v .log`
    " :vimgrep /srch/ `find . -type f -name '*.pm' -o -name '*.pl'`
    "
    " how-to search for the "srch" from the current dir recursively in the shell
    " vim -c ':vimgrep /srch/ `find . -type f \| grep -v .git \| grep -v .log`'
    "
    " how-to highlight the after the search the searchable string
    " in normmal mode press g* when the cursor is on a matched string

    " how-to jump between the search matches - open the quick fix window by
    " :copen 22

    " how-to to close the quick fix window
    " :ccl

    " F5 will find the next occurrence after vimgrep
    map <F5> :cp!<CR>

    " F6 will find the previous occurrence after vimgrep
    map <F6> :cn!<CR>

    " F8 search for word under the cursor recursively , :copen , to close -> :ccl
    nnoremap <F8> :grep! "\<<cword>\>" . -r<CR>:copen 33<CR>

    " omit a dir from all searches to perform globally
    set wildignore+=**/node_modules/**

    " use perl regexes - src: http://andrewradev.com/2011/05/08/vim-regexes/
    noremap / /\v
    "
    " STOP  search related configs and helps
```

Comment: I like a lot your F5-F8 ideas. It would be nice to have some visualisations/outputs of those commands here. How is F8 designed to work? It searches only the current directory? - - The omit of a dir is a custom - - why `node_modules`? - - How perl regexes change Vim's default functioning? - - The following is how I have designed my search of .tex files https://askubuntu.com/a/789769/25388 It would be nice to learn from you how to improve it. It is not so intuitive so I forgot the logic myself often too.

Comment: node_modules is the dir containing a lot of js code from the npm modules if you would develop front-ends ... it is just an example ...

Comment: make a backup of you .vimrc and add those settings , load them with :so % and than try to run the "helps" in the commands ... vim is hard - you would have to repeat those thousands of times, but once you master them you will laugh @everyone who points their gread new UI IDE features ...

Answer (score 254):

```
:g//p
```

In its longer form:

```
:global/regular-expression/print
```

You can leave out the pattern/regex and Vim will re-use the previous search term.

*Trivia:* The [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) tool was named after this command sequence.

Comment: `:g//` - since p(rint) is the default action, you can leave that out too.

Comment: `:g/` is even shorter!

Comment: Is it possible to see context here, like in grep `--context 9`?

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich Try `:%s/regular-expression//gn`                                      
It will produce something along these lines: `X matches on Y lines`

Comment: @AlexejMagura I mean - how to see few lines before and after of string?

Comment: What should I do to highlight the word in the result-list of `:g/abc/`, and how to just to the specific line of the result using key like j/k or other keys?

Answer (score 57):

You can also do a :

`g/pattern/#`

that will print the pattern you want and the number of the line.

Comment: Nice one. But if you have line numbers already enabled, then `#` is not required. It shows line numbers by default

Answer (score 48):

if you want to look at this list and jump quickly between the matches, consider using

`:vimgrep example %`

or

`:grep example %`

This will populate the "error list" with all of the matches so that you can use `:copen` to list them all in the quickfix buffer, press enter on a particular line to jump to that match, or use commands like `:cn` and `:cp` to go back and forth.

for a thorough explanation, see [my reply to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537431/redirection-to-a-file-of-a-search-in-vim/545243#545243)

Comment: This gives `E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h"` on MacVim 8.1

Comment: @LincolnBergeson that issue may be caused by working with a buffer that doesn't have a file name. It just happened to me :-) https://stackoverflow.com/a/35136241/239408

Answer (score 38):

Just learned a new one: the `Location List`!
Type `:lvim foo %` to search for `foo` in the current file and enter all matches containing `foo` into the *location list*.
Type `:lopen` to open the location list in the quickfix window, which is fully navigable as usual.
Use `:lnext`/`:lprevious` to to through the list (use *tpope/unimpaired* mappings for the best experience)

Comment: Nice tip! this led me to make this mapping that automatically expands the word under cursor and does lopen in one sweep: nnoremap <leader>f :lvim /<c-r>=expand("<cword>")<cr>/ %<cr>:lopen<cr>

Answer (score 19):

Another possibility is to use the include file search commands.

```
[I
```

This will list all occurrences of the word under the cursor. It may be more than you need though, because it will also search any files that are included in the current file.

But the nice thing about this command is that the search result display also shows a count of the number of matches, in addition to the line number of each match.

```
:help include-search
```

to see lots of variants.

A note about

```
:g//p
```

This can be reduced further to

```
:g//
```

because, as others have said, p(rint) is the default action.

Comment: Is it possible to get result from `[I` with context, like on grep `--context 9`?

Answer (score 15):

you can get a nice `quickfix` window with the matches form your current search pattern

```
:vim // %
:copen
```

super handy if you previously crafted a complex search pattern using just `/pattern`

**Edit**: just found out this also works for all open buffers

```
:bufdo vimgrepadd // %
:copen
```

Answer (score 10):

Using `:set hlsearch` will highlight all the matches in yellow allowing you to scan the file easily for matches.  That may not be what you want though, after searching, :g//p will give you the listed matches

Comment: Should be ':set hlsearch' not ':hlsearch'.

Comment: It's useful to also map `:nohl` to clear the highlights when you don't need them anymore.

Answer (score 9):

To elaborate on this ... instead of

```
/example
:g//p
```

you can also write directly

```
:g/example/p
```

or, as p(rint) is the default action for the :g(lobal) command, this can be shortened to

```
:g/example
```

And instead of p(rint), other actions are possible, e.g. d(elete). See :help :global

Answer (score 7):

```
g/pattern
```

If you have `:set number`, the above command displays line numbers as well.

If you haven't `:set number`, then

```
g/pattern/#
```

will display the line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a piece of code for this. It actually avoids the problems in `vimgrep`. It works even with unnamed files. And it is easier to use.

```
function! Matches(pat)
    let buffer=bufnr("") "current buffer number
    let b:lines=[]
    execute ":%g/" . a:pat . "/let b:lines+=[{'bufnr':" . 'buffer' . ", 'lnum':" . "line('.')" . ", 'text': escape(getline('.'),'\"')}]"
    call setloclist(0, [], ' ', {'items': b:lines}) 
    lopen
endfunction
```

When you call it with a pattern, it opens the location windows with all the matches.

This could be a command

```
command! -nargs=1 Mat call Matches(<f-args>)
```

So all you need to do is to type `:Mat pattern`

I also use the following mapping to get the matches of the current visual selection.

```
vnoremap Y "xy:call Matches(@x)<CR>
```

Comment: I really like this approach, especially the fact that it works on unsaved buffers. In my setup, I added a normal mode mapping: `nnoremap Y :call Matches(@/)<CR>` to display every line of my current search pattern.

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl-f to list all search result:

```
nmap <C-f> :vimgrep /<C-r>//g %<CR> \| !:copen <Enter>
```