# Selectable list of occurrences of searched word in current file.

Tags: search, vim

[You can use the following to get a list of matches in a file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509690/how-can-you-list-the-matches-of-vims-search)

`:g/<MATCH_THIS>/p`

Is there a way to make this list selectable similar to the [Ag.vim plugin](https://github.com/rking/ag.vim)?

> Files containing the search term will be listed in the split window, along with the line number of the occurrence, once for each occurrence. [Enter] on a line in this window will open the file, and place the cursor on the matching line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:vimgrep/pattern/g %
```

Or maybe something like this:

```
nnoremap <leader>/ :vimgrep/<c-r>//g %<cr>:copen<cr>
```

Vimcast did a nice episode on this topic: [Search multiple files with :vimgrep](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/)

For more help see:

```
:h :vimgrep
:h :caddexpr
```

Comment: Vimgrep is good at finding and having an array of the matches but doesn't do the same thing as Ag.vim. 

Looking for something similar to https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/XzN4h4dj4cE/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: What is Ag.vim doing that is so special in your screenshot? Did you open the quickfix window via `:copen`?

Comment: The quickfix windows gives a list, but you can't just hit enter and jump to the line similar to Ag.vim.

Comment: Sounds like something is wrong here. `<cr>` in the quickfix window is the same as `:.cc`, see `:helpgrep :\.cc`. You may want to do `:verbose nmap <buffer>` on the quickfix window.

Comment: Hmm looks like my <CR> was mapping to something else.... Fixed it using
`:autocmd BufReadPost quickfix nnoremap <buffer> <CR> <CR>`

Is there a function that does all the following? 
`:vimgrep/<INPUT-JUMPS-HERE>/g %` and then calls `:copen`?

Comment: You can chain commands via the `|`. e.g. `:vimgrep/foo/ %|cope`. However I find that I do not open up the quickfix window too much with good mappings to `:cnext` and `:cprev`. I use `]q` and `[q` which are provided by Tim Pope's [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin. However I am sure you could create a custom command to do this or use the mapping in the post above. However I imagine what you want is something like this `autocmd QuickFixCmdPost vimgrep copen`