# vim: ":source %" command results in error: E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h"

Tags: vim

How do I resolve this error:

```
E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h"
```

This error happens anytime I use `%` in a vim command. I've never seen this before. Here is my .vimrc:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
"Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
"Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'
"Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
```

I've commented out those last few plugins to see if they had any correlation with the error, but that didn't seem to help. I used Git to install vim as usual:

```
git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

All I did after that was run `:PluginInstall` to install the plugins, and then ran `:source %` which gave the error.

OS: Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be related to an empty `%`. You can do two things: pass the filename when invoking vim: `vim myscript.vim` and then calling `:source %`, or passing the filename to `:source` (`:source myscript.vim`).

Per the docs, `:help registers` lists `%` as a read-only register containing the current filename. So, if you are editing a buffer that doesn't have a filename (not saved), this `%` register is empty, resulting in the error message that you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I am having another issue that I will try to resolve on my own, and update here if I can't figure it out. Also running into quite a few unrelated problems on this install of Ubuntu, many file permission and configuration errors.

Answer (score 1):

This error is displayed when :source % is used after opening vim without any files. What you could do is open vim with a file name e.g. vim file1.js , and then try :source %