# vim: list the search results, find one of them then jump back

Tags: list, search, vim

I am editing one file and knew the globle search and list according to [How can you list the matches of Vim's search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509690/how-can-you-list-the-matches-of-vims-search)
that is `:g/table*/p`

It can list the search resultss of the current file in another window.
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1YDp.png)

Is there a way to jump back to the line #413 where this result is from the list window?

Or the only way is to quit first then enter `413G`?

Answer (score 2):

If understand your question: first, the command `:vimgrep` fills the quickfix list with all the matches.

Then, you can navigate between them by doing either

(a) `:cnext` and `:cprev` (`[q` and `]q` if you use unimpaired); or

(b) `:copen`, navigate the quickfix window with normal commands, and `<CR>` to open the match.

To get back to the quickfix window, you can use normal window navigation commands (`:h windows`) such as the `<C-w>`/`:wincmd` family, or use `:copen`.

See `:h quickfix`.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for my awkward expression. But I mean to do internal search.

Comment: @JosephWANG what do you mean by internal search? Like vimgrep or like `/`

Answer (score -2):

for file search, you have the Plugin [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf).

but, for text search you have the vim-scripts/grep.vim Plugin

you may try to strart building your .vimrc from [vim-bootstrap](https://vim-bootstrap.com/).

check out my vimrc @[Github](https://github.com/reubinoff/myVimrc)